# How to disable default app permissions for Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a Facebook app, but I don't think I need the default permissions from my users ("public info" and the user's email address)

I'd like to keep the permissions requested to a bare minimum, but I can't see in my app admin area on developers.facebook.com anywhere to disable these.

How can I just ask for what I want and turn these off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to disable those permissions, just don´t ask for them in the login process. They are only "approved", which means that you don´t need to go through a review process IF you want to use them. More information about login review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: Ok I'll take this at face value, thanks! Also thanks for the link.